# SCNAction.removeFromParentNode and deinit not called

Tags: ios, swift, memory, scenekit, deinit

the following method is defined inside a class extension of GKComponent

```
weak var node:SCNNode?
```

...

```
 func moveAlongNorthSouth() {
       let moveAction = SCNAction.moveByX(0, y: 0, z: 1, duration: NSTimeInterval(2))
       let sequence = SCNAction.sequence([moveAction,SCNAction.removeFromParentNode()])
       self.node!.runAction(sequence)
   }
```

The last action is `SCNAction.removeFromParentNode()`, performed after the moveAction.

The node is correctly removed from the graph scene but the deinit of related node is not called and I cannot free the memory...

BUT, if if I remove the moveAction from the sequence than deinit is called. It is a bug??

`func moveAlongNorthSouth() {
        let sequence = SCNAction.sequence([SCNAction.removeFromParentNode()])
        self.node!.runAction(sequence)
    }`

Comment: I'm surprised that deinit is called in the second example you posted as I'd expect a reference would be maintained (preventing deinit) via `self.node`, this could of course be a weak reference.  What if you set `self.node = nil` after the run action?

Comment: yes, node is defined as weak reference: weak var node:SCNNode?

Comment: I have investigate more and I discover the following behaviour. If I set the duration of moveAction to 0.1 sec then the deinit method is called!!!!!

Comment: Hard to explain that. May be worth a bug report to Apple.